# I can't fix this error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, swiftui, google-signin

I am trying to implement a google signin option to my application but I keep getting an error

I searched online, on what this error means, but people were saying it is causes by wrong argument names.

but I don't see anything wrong with this.

this is my code:

```
private func googleLogIn() {
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
    
    let config = GIDConfiguration(clientID: clientID)
    
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: config, presenting: self) { [unowned self] user, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let email = user?.profile?.email,
              let firstName = user?.profile?.givenName,
              let lastName = user?.profile?.familyName else {
                  return
              }
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: Keys.email.rawValue)
        UserDefaults.standard.set("\(firstName) \(lastName)", forKey: Keys.name.rawValue)
        
        DatabaseManager.shared.userExists(with: email) { exists in
            if !exists {
                
                let chatUser = ChatAppUser(firstName: firstName,
                                           lastName: lastName,
                                           emailAddress: email)
                DatabaseManager.shared.insertUser(with: chatUser) { success in
                    if success {
                        
                        // upload image
                        
                        if ((user?.profile?.hasImage) != nil) {
                            guard let url = user?.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 200) else {
                                return
                            }
                            
                            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, _ in
                                guard let data = data else {
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                let filename = chatUser.profilePictureFileName
                                StorageManager.shared.uploadProfilePicture(with: data,
                                                                           filename: filename) { result in
                                    switch result {
                                    case .success(let downloadUrl):
                                        UserDefaults.standard.set(downloadUrl, forKey: Keys.profilePictureUrl.rawValue)
                                        print(downloadUrl)
                                    case .failure(let error):
                                        print(error)
                                    }
                                }
                            }.resume()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        guard let authentication = user?.authentication,
              let idToken = authentication.idToken else {
                  return
              }
        
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            
            guard authResult != nil, error == nil else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to sign in with Google: \(error)")
                }
                return
            }
            print("Successfully logged user in")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .didLogInNotification, object: nil)
            strongSelf.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The same error occurs several times in my code.
Is it possible I am missing some packages?

Comment: Can you at least point out the lines giving the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug "ambiguous" errors, simplify the code until the error goes away, and see what's creating it. For example, remove the entire contents of each closure and see if the error goes away. Then add pieces back, bit by bit. Delete parts that are known to be ok to simplify the rest of the expressions and help the compiler give you a better error. Extract individual pieces into functions, which will often give better error messages (and be better code anyway). A single 85-line method with multiple nested closures should be split up even if you weren't getting errors.